Issue with netcat-tarditional and docker
I have a  bash script in my docker container that use netcat to receive a datagram from a raspberry with this command:
msg_port=60001
nc -k -u -l -p $msg_port >> /data/hydro/info.txt &

Now, i have tested this script on my computer (outside of container) and it works.
But when i run it with a container, that use netcat-traditional, in the first run it works perfectly. But if i restart the script in the raspberry without restarting the container, it seems to no longer receive data, even if it remains listening.
I think the problem is that the netcat command is unable to accept new connections, althought -k option should be used to avoid this problem.
I repeat that, outside of the container, everything works

What are the exact version of nc on the host machine where the script has been tested and in the container?

@OrtomalaLokni version of nc on the host machine is 1.226-1 (netcat-OpenBsd) and version in the container is 1.10-48 (netcat-traditional)

You should try to use nc 1.226-1 (netcat-OpenBsd) in the container.

I had already tried, but ran into this problem package netcat has no installation candidate and had to switch to netcat-traditional

I solved the problem. At the beginning I had written apt install netcat in the dockerfile, so I had come across this problem package netcat has no installation whose solution was to specify the netcat package. due to my forgetfulness, instead of writing apt install netcat-openbsd I had written apt install netcat-traditional, thinking that that package was installed on the host (where the command worked)
